# How to make my shell implementation terminate Node.JS after two Ctrl+C signals?

Tags: c, node.js, shell, signals

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char** args){
    char *buffer = (char*) malloc(2048);
    char *cmd = (char*) malloc(2048);
    pid_t pid;
    while(1) {
        printf("!! ");
        fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin);
        if( buffer[0] != '\n') {
            pid = fork();
            if( pid == 0){
                buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';
                execvp(buffer, args);                
                exit(1);
            }else if(pid > 0){
                waitpid(pid, 0, WUNTRACED);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know that above code is ugly but I would like to show simplified version of my original code so I made it simplified as it is possible but I show a problem as well.

Ok, so I am testing my shell:
1. I compiled.
2. I ran it and:

`!! racket`. It gives me:

```
!! racket
Welcome to Racket v6.2.
>
```

And it is ok. And, what is important, I am able to finish this process with Ctrl-C. When I put Ctrl-C:

```
!! racket
Welcome to Racket v6.2.
> ^C
user break
  context...:
   /usr/local/share/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:87:7
>
$ ( this dolar is from my bash)
```

So it also work as we are expecting. But the problem is with `js`. I mean 
`js = nodejs - Server-side JavaScript`. Where is the problem? Let see:

```
   !! js
>
```

It look like OK. But, when I put: Ctrl-C:

```
!! js
> 
(^C again to quit)
>
```

Ok, so I put again: Ctrl-C:

```
!! js
> 
(^C again to quit)
> 
>
```

and it doesn't finish a process. It sill works. And it is a problem. I don't understand this behaviour and I don't know how to repair it. 
P.S In bash/zsh it works.

Comment: Why have you aliased `node` (or `nodejs`) to `js`? That's just confusing.

Comment: I don't know why. But it is.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you set your implementation as your login shell, so that bash is not involved? Make sure you have a way to set it back of course.

Comment: There is no difference.